# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'data.detailInfo' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { InfoConsumer } from '../context';

class Details extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <InfoConsumer>
                {data => {
                    const {
                        id,
                        headerTitle,
                        headerSubTitle,
                        headerText,
                        img,
                        title,
                        maps,
                        description
                    } = data.detailInfo;
                    return (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <div className="conteiner-fluid align-items-center">
                                <h1 className='display-1 font-weight-bold'>{headerTitle}</h1>
                                <h4 className='display-5'>{headerSubTitle}</h4>
                                <p>{headerText}</p>
                            </div>
                        </React.Fragment>
                    );
                }}

            </InfoConsumer>
        );
    }
}

export default Details;
```

I  check for undefined in JavaScript is **using the strict equality operator, === , and comparing it to the primitive undefined** . Checking for `undefined`` this way will work in every use case except for one, if the variable hasn't been declared yet.

Comment: Are you just asking how to check if something is `undefined` in JavaScript?

Comment: There's no key named 'id' inside the data.detailInfo

Comment: You haven't shown where you check for undefined. This would indicate that `data.detailInfo` is sometimes `undefined` which can't be destructured. You can either conditionally render based on data.detailInfo: `return ( data.detailInfo === undefined? null : <InfoConsumer> {data => {`or assign a default empty object: `} = data?.detailInfo??{};` (you probably want the former)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) in order to preserve `data.detailInfo` value consistent overall regardless of state changes.

So that, only changing line that includes `} = data.detailInfo;` to `} = data?.detailInfo;`, will prevent it to be rendered when **detailInfo** property of "data" is `undefined`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { InfoConsumer } from '../context';

class Details extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <InfoConsumer>
                {data => {
                    const {
                        id,
                        headerTitle,
                        headerSubTitle,
                        headerText,
                        img,
                        title,
                        maps,
                        description
                    } = data?.detailInfo;
                    return (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <div className="conteiner-fluid align-items-center">
                                <h1 className='display-1 font-weight-bold'>{headerTitle}</h1>
                                <h4 className='display-5'>{headerSubTitle}</h4>
                                <p>{headerText}</p>
                            </div>
                        </React.Fragment>
                    );
                }}

            </InfoConsumer>
        );
    }
}

export default Details;
```